# Python win32com.client pauses from Visio error and does not continue to execute rest of code

Tags: python, visio, win32com

I'm opening and archiving Visio files.

```
visio = comclt.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
wsh= comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.AppActivate("Microsoft Visio")

for i in os.listdir(path): #loops through the path
    if i[-3:]=='vsd': #checks to see if it is a visio file
        doc = visio.Documents.Open(path+'\\'+i)
```

But when I open certain Visio files, because the visio file was created on a different machine where a local stencil was present, there is an error of `.vss is part of workspace but cannot be opened`. This is not a problem, I can just hit `ok`. So I've put in code to send key `ENTER`.

Here is my problem. I have the code below. But it does't work because (I think) the code pauses on `doc = visio.Documents.Open(path+'\\'+i)` and does not continue until `ok` is pressed. Once I press `ok` manually, the code sleeps for 2 seconds before continuing.

```
time.sleep(2)
wsh.AppActivate("Microsoft Visio")
wsh.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

how do I tell python to not wait for `doc = visio.Documents.Open(path+'\\'+i)`? or is another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use .AlertResponse to prevent message boxes in Visio:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767782.aspx

i.e. before opening the diagram, set

Visio.AlertResponse = 1

This should prevent the message from popping up.

Comment: where do I put that code? Can you give me an example?

Comment: try putting it just after creating visio. That is:


visio = comclt.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
visio.AlertResponse = 1